# How to use sed to replace a command followed by 0 or more spaces in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I can't figure out how to replace a comma followed by 0 or more spaces in a bash variable. here's what i have:

```
base="test00 test01 test02 test03"
options="test04,test05, test06"

for b in $(echo $options | sed "s/, \+/ /g")
do
  base="${base} $b"
done
```

What i'm trying to do is append the "options" to the "base". Options is user input which can be empty or a csv list however that list can be

"test04, test05, test06" -> space after the comma

"test04,test05,test06" -> no spaces

"test04,test05, test06" -> mixture

what i need is my output "base" to be a space delimited list however no matter what i try my list keeps getting cut off after the first word.

My expected out is

"test00 test01 test02 test03 test04 test05 test06"

Comment: try `sed "s/, */ /g"` .. `\+` means `1 or more spaces`... `*` means `0 or more spaces`

Comment: What does this have to do with a "command"? If you're trying to generate a command in shell, rather than format a string, you want to use completely different techniques (see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for details).

Comment: @spasic i added my expected out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i'm trying to format a string not generate a command, not sure i understand your question

Comment: @socalcheesehead, ...then you should probably avoid using the phrase "replace a command" in your question title, as it certainly makes it *sound* like your real goal is something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for sed, bash has built in pattern substitution [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).  With bash 3.0 or later, `extglob` added support for more advanced [regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Extended_Globs).

```
# Enables extended regular expressions for +(pattern)
shopt -s extglob

# Replaces all comma-space runs with just a single space
options="${options//,+( )/ }"
```

If you don't have bash 3.0+ available or don't like enabling `extglob`, simply strip all spaces which will work most of the time:

```
# Remove all spaces
options="${options// /}"

# Then replace commas with spaces
options="${options//,/ }"
```

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to generate a command, this technique is wrong altogether: As described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), command arguments should be stored in an array, not a whitespace-delimited string.

```
base=( test00 test01 test02 test03 )
IFS=', ' read -r -a options_array <<<"$options"

# ...and, to execute the result:
"${base[@]}" "${options_array[@]}"
```

That said, even this isn't adequate to many legitimate use cases: Consider what happens if you want to pass an option that contains literal whitespace -- for instance, running `./your-base-command "base argument with spaces" "second base argument" "option with spaces" "option with spaces" "second option with spaces"`. For that, you need something like the following:

```
base=( ./your-base-command "base argument with spaces" "second base argument" )
options="option with spaces, second option with spaces"

# read options into an array, splitting on commas
IFS=, read -r -a options_array <<<"$options"

# trim leading and trailing spaces from array elements
options_array=( "${options_array[@]% }" )
options_array=( "${options_array[@]# }" )

# ...and, to execute the result:
"${base[@]}" "${options_array[@]}"
```